# When does Spring Security OAuth2 check access token expiration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm debugging a scenario in my production environment where I intermittently see unexpected HTTP 401 responses from my resource server.  I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 (the "old" OAuth libraries; pre Spring Security 5.2.x and its implementation of OAuth2) to handle requests and perform Authn.

What I'm observing is the following:

1. A user logs in at time `x` (time in seconds here) and obtains an access token.  That access token expires at time `x + 900` (15 minute validity).
2. At time `x + 480`, the user makes a request to a protected endpoint.
3. The request takes a long time to complete, such that it's still being processed when the token expires.  At time `x + 900`, the server returns a `HTTP 401` response.

Questions:

1. Is this really how Spring Security OAuth2 works?  To be more specific, does it track the token's expiration time and return a 401 if the request is still being processed when the token expires?  Or on the other end of the security filter, when the response is being prepared?
2. Is there a way to disable this behavior, so that the token is only checked when the request is first processed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source code for `spring-security-oauth2` and this is not how it works.  The token expiration is only checked one time, at the beginning of processing of the request.

I traced the issue I was having above to a problem in which our server resources were maxed out for a period.  When resources (CPU; HTTP request worker threads) became available, the server started processing the request, but by this time the token had expired.